# What is the time complexity of getting the max key of a std::map in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, std

I'm trying to find the largest value in a `std::map`, which would be the last node in the tree (since `std::map` keys are sorted).

Cppref says `std::map.end()` is constant time. But to get the largest key, I must get the previous value of this iterator, i.e. `*std::prev(std::map.end())`.

What's the time complexity of that operation?

I understand that this should equivalent to `--std::map.end()`, but I don't know the cost of that operation either.

Comment: Try `std::map::rbegin()`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Try the answer section :P

Comment: Got beat by too many answers.  Oh well.

Comment: Well @PaulMcKenzie I answered about the time your comment was posted! And I answered first, so you could have done it! ;) Next time, use the answers section. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an [`std::map::rbegin()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/rbegin/) instead, which:

> Returns a reverse iterator pointing to the last element in the container (i.e., its reverse beginning).

and:

> ### Complexity
>
> Constant.

where the last word should sound like music in your ears.

---

`std::prev(std::map.end())` is [constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) in complexity.

---

Moreover, your understanding about the equivalency is wrong.

From [`std::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) notes:

> Although the expression `--c.end()` *often* compiles, it is not
>   guaranteed to do so: `c.end()` is an rvalue expression, and there is
>   no iterator requirement that specifies that decrement of an rvalue is
>   guaranteed to work. In particular, when iterators are implemented as
>   pointers, `--c.end()` does *not* compile, while `std::prev(c.end())`
>   does.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly works, though I must confess I am still curious: how would I find out the time complexity of `std::prev(std::map.end())`?

Comment: Updated @DunPeal, moreover, your last part of your question shows that you didn't understand exactly the equivalence.

Comment: @DunPeal `how would I find out the time complexity of ...` The authoritative source of information for complexity guarantees of standard functions is the standard document. There are also unofficial websites that provide the same information in a more convenient format.

Answer (score 5):

[Advancing in any direction is linear in the number of advances](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) (in your case that's *one*, so we can call it constant-time), but you don't need to do it. Just use `rbegin()` which is an iterator to the last element.

`std::prev` is *not* equivalent to `--std::map.end()` though, the latter of which is not guaranteed to do anything useful at all. See the [`std::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) docs.

Comment: What if I call it on an iterator that does not meet ` BidirectionalIterator`?  Compilation error?

Comment: @DunPeal Try it and see! Another reason to just use `rbegin()`.

Answer (score 3):

> But to get the largest key, I must get the previous value of this iterator, i.e. `*std::prev(std::map.end())`.
>
> What's the time complexity of that operation?

All of `std::map.end`, `std::prev(a_std_map_iterator)` and `std::map::iterator::operator*` are constant operations. Therefore that expression is constant as a whole.

Note that the complexity of `std::prev` is guaranteed to be at most linear in terms of the second argument `n`, which is defaulted to 1. When `n` is constant, `std::prev` as a whole is constant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit indeed. Constant, but not optimal.